# mysql soccer standings table with home and away stats

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate

I have the below data in a mysql database, there are extra fields like the referee, yellow cards, red cards, home team shot, away team shots, home shots on target, away shots on target.

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id  |   hometeam   |  homegoals  |  awaygoals  |  awayteam  | results  |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |Brighton      |   3         |     1       | Nott'm Frst|    H     |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |Birmingham    |   1         |     3       | Reading    |    A     |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  |Nott'm frst   |   4         |     4       | Brighton   |    D     |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What i would like to output is a standings table with the following details

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------
|                   Overall    |   Away    | Home             |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
|pos  |   team   |P|W|D|L|F|A| |W|D|L|F|A| |W|D|L|F|A| |GD|Pts|
 --------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   |Brighton  |2|1|1|0|7|4| |0|1|0|4|4| |1|0|0|3|1| |-1| 4 |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
| 2   |Nott'm fst|2|0|1|1|5|3| |0|0|1|1|3| |0|1|0|4|4| |-1| 1 |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
```

The rest of the information can be achieved by accessing each team page. My query works ok for the overall section, however, the other details are becoming difficult to obtain.

Query as below

```
select 
    team, 
    count(*) P, 
    count(case when fulltimehomegoals > fulltimeawaygoals then 1 end) W, 
    count(case when fulltimeawaygoals> fulltimehomegoals then 1 end) L, 
    count(case when fulltimehomegoals = fulltimeawaygoals then 1 end) D, 
    sum(fulltimehomegoals) F, 
    sum(fulltimeawaygoals) A, 
    sum(fulltimehomegoals) - sum(fulltimeawaygoals) GD,
    sum(
          case when fulltimehomegoals > fulltimeawaygoals then 3 else 0 end 
        + case when fulltimehomegoals = fulltimeawaygoals then 1 else 0 end
    ) Pts 
from (
    select hometeam team, fulltimehomegoals, fulltimeawaygoals, fulltimeresults from fixtures 
  union all
    select awayteam, fulltimeawaygoals, fulltimehomegoals, fulltimeresults from fixtures
) a 
group by team
order by Pts desc, GD desc;
```

Kindly give direction on sections that need editing to achieve the end result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d82b87

Comment: You need to explain what each of this `P|W|D|L|F|A` means and from what fields they are calculated from! Otherwise its just guessing here.

Comment: @JorgeCampos kindly view this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d82b87 to work around sample database

Comment: Can you explain what each of `|P|W|D|L|F|A| |W|D|L|F|A| |W|D|L|F|A| |GD|Pts` represent?

Comment: This is the same link provided in your second comment I already saw it. My state remains. There is nothing that explain what is each of that initials. There is no field equivalence for then. You writed your question assuming everyone here knows what should they be. This is wrong, MUST assume the NO ONE knows what you have beside you, therefore you have to explain it in details. You have to explain everything like `P - stands for number of games that was played by that is on the hometeam field, W - represents bla bla bla..., etc.`

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr I asked him already and it seems that the OP didn't understand.

Comment: Overall section
P - total number of games played, count(hometeam) + count(awayteam) fields
W - total number of wins, counting occurence of H in fulltimeresults field
D - total number of draws, counting D in fulltimeresults field
L - total number of losses, if team is at home then awayteamgoals is more than hometeamgoals; if team is away then hometeamgoals is more than awayteamgoals
F - total goals scored by team ie hometeamgoals plus awayteamgoals
A - total goals scored by other teams

Comment: Away section
W - wins while away
D - draws while away
L - losses while away
F - goals scored while away
A - goals scored by home-team

Comment: Home section
W - wins while team is home
D - draws while team is home
L - losses while team is home
F - goals scored while team is home
A - goals scored by away team

GD - goal difference ie sum(F) - sum(A)
Pts - total points accrud (win=3points, draw=1point)